# Right align image in multirow environment

Tags: tables, graphics, horizontal-alignment, multirow

I am trying to create a simple template for lab reports with my university's logo embedded in a multirow environment, and **I would like the logo to be horizontally aligned to the far right of the table**, however the logo stubbornly sticks to the left, and is not even vertically centred:

[image]

Here I put the debian logo as a placeholder. Logo should be at the far right, independently of the text on its left.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}


\hrule
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{l r}
\textbf {\large{Course :} Course name} & \multirow{2}{*}{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{logo}} \\
\large Lab name & \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{l l}
{\textbf{Name:}\ Student Name} & \textbf{Due Date:} date  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\hrule

\end{document}
```

I figured that the multirow package would be the easiest solution, but any other method is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\tabular` just takes on the minimum space that it needs. I guess you want to put the logo at the right of the text area, not at the right of the table.

Also you don't need the `table` environments. These are for floating materials with a caption.

If this is the only text in the header, there is not need for these `\tabular`s at all, except to put the two line text Course and Lab Name.
That means no `\multirow`.

And vertically entering an image requires a `\raisebox`.

This gives the following solution:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\hrule
\noindent\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l}
\textbf {\large{Course :} Course name}\\
\large Lab name \\
\end{tabular}
\hfill\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{logo}} \\
{\textbf{Name:}\ Student Name} \hspace{1cm} \textbf{Due Date:} date  \\
\hrule

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, exactly what I needed. If I correctly understand your code, you are embedding the logo inside of a box, which is lifted up (with \raisebox I guess) to align with the text on the left. Is it generally a bad idea of putting an image inside of a table like I did?

Comment: Actually, the `makebox` was my first attempt (using the `[c]` to center it), which didn't work. And in fact, you can leave out the `\makebox` and just use the `\raisebox`. And you can do the same thing inside a `tabular`. So I will take out the `\makebox`.